# Wordpress class-wp-image-editor.php permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress, image-editor

I just changed the directory of my WordPress instance. I copied all files via FTP into the new folder and also copied the database and edited the site URL and home entries.

Now the page don't show the images, but gives me this message:

> Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open
>   '/www/htdocs/serverID/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/modell3-2xr5ffo5juzmz3rgn84d8g.jpg'
>   for writing: Permission denied in
>   /www/htdocs/w00db707/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php on line 405

Everything else is looking good. Do you know whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

1. The file/folder permissions for `/wp-content/uploads/` need to be `CHMOD` to `0755` or `0777`
2. If the permissions are already set to 0755 or 0777, the owning user/group needs to match your HTTPD user (varies based on server configuration; sometimes the user is `www-data`, sometimes `apache`, if a Plesk environment it is the username you setup the subscription with)